# Are the inverse of "nearly" diagonal nonsingular matrices also "nearly" diagonal?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Assumption: Given a sequence of square matrices $P^k, k=1,2, ..., n$ with $\lim_{k \to \infty} P^k_{ij} = 0$ for $i \neq j$ (but the diagonal element of $P^k$ may not converge). Moreover, the determinant of the sequence is a constant, suppose $\det P_k = 1, k=1,2, ... n$.

Question: Let $U^k = (P^k)^{-1}$. I am wondering if $\lim_{k \to \infty} U^k_{ij} = 0$, for $i \neq j$?

Currently, I think perhaps we can start from the equaiton:
$$
U^k_{ij} = \frac{C^k_{ji}}{\det P^k}
$$
, where $C^k_{ji}$ is the $(j, i)$ cofactor of $P^k$. But I can not go through further.

Also, it might by easier if we suppose the diagonal elements of $P^k, k=1,2, ..., n$ are uniformly bounded so that $P^k$ has a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it turns out. For example, if
$\displaystyle
P^k = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{k} & \frac{1}{k} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{k} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & k^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$, then
$\displaystyle
U^k = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & -k & 0 \\
 0 & k & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{k^2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$.

On the other hand, if we assume in addition that the diagonal elements of the $P^k$ are uniformly bounded, then the answer is yes. The reason is that each $U_{ij}^k = C_{ij}^k$; each such cofactor entries is a determinant of a matrix that has uniformly bounded entries and one row/column all of whose entries tend to $0$ as $k\to\infty$, and such determinants then must tend to $0$. (To see this, write the determinant as an alternating sum of products of entries of the matrix, or "factor out an $\varepsilon$" from the special row/column.)

Comment: Thank you for your example! Would you like to give answer this problem if we add an additional assumption that the diagonal elements of $P_k$ are bounded?

Comment: edited with the other case

Comment: That is clear. Thanks again!